# Selecting multiple table classes in jQuery loop

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have a table that uses jQuery & [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to get the time from a column, check if the time is greater than X minutes from now, and if so, highlight the cell.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/kjscq4ra/

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td class="person">Jack "Smith"</td>
        <td class="time">8/03/2016 8:35:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>246</td>
        <td class="person">John "A" Doe</td>
        <td class="time">8/03/2016 7:05:30 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>369</td>
        <td class="person">Jane</td>
        <td class="time">8/03/2016 7:15:25 AM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('#myTable td.time').each(function() {
    var cellText = $(this).text();
    var a = moment();
    var b = moment(cellText, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
    var difference = a.diff(b, 'minutes');
    if (difference >= 60) {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#FFBABA');
    };
});
```

I'd like to add a condition to my `if` statement to also check the "person" column for certain text before highlighting the "time" column. For example, only highlight the "time" column if the "person" `td` contains an apostrophe in the name:

```
$("#myTable td.person:contains('\"\')")
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this below fiddle

```js
$('#myTable td.time').each(function() {
  if ($(this).siblings("td.person").html().indexOf("\"") > -1) {
  var cellText = $(this).text();
    var a = moment();
    var b = moment(cellText, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
    var difference = a.diff(b, 'minutes');
    if (difference >= 60) {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#FFBABA');
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td class="person">Jack "Smith"</td>
    <td class="time">8/03/2016 8:35:00 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>246</td>
    <td class="person">John "A" Doe</td>
    <td class="time">8/03/2016 7:05:30 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>369</td>
    <td class="person">Jane</td>
    <td class="time">8/03/2016 7:15:25 AM</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[See jQuery's `prev` function](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$('#myTable td.time').each(function() {
  var $timeCell = $(this),
    cellText = $timeCell.text(),
    personText = $timeCell.prev('.person').text(),
    a = moment(),
    b = moment(cellText, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss"),
    difference = a.diff(b, 'minutes');

  if (difference >= 60 && personText.indexOf('"') > -1) {
    $timeCell.css('background-color', '#FFBABA');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kjscq4ra/4/

Answer (score 0):

May be try with this. You can use **$.prev/$.siblings** to get the element and check for its value

```
$('#myTable td.time').each(function() {
  if( $(this).prev('td.person').text().match(/\"|\'/)) 
 {
  var cellText = $(this).text();
  var a = moment();
  var b = moment(cellText, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
  var difference = a.diff(b, 'minutes');
  if (difference >= 60) {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FFBABA');
  };
 }
});
```